# How to reproduce/sanitize messy POST params to avoid YAML serialization issues with delayed_job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml, delayed-job

Today, every time I was starting `delayed_job` workers, the process would die immediately and silently.

After some investigation (and finding out about the foreground mode of `delayed_job`), I finally found out the problem was the way `delayed_job` had serialized my active record object was triggering an exception on the YAML load part:

```
Psych::SyntaxError: (<unknown>): mapping keys are not allowed in this context at line 7 column 14
from /Users/mick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse'
from /Users/mick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse_stream'
from /Users/mick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:151:in `parse'
from /Users/mick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:127:in `load'
from /Users/mick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/safe_yaml-0.9.7/lib/safe_yaml.rb:144:in `load_with_options'
from (irb):111
from /Users/mick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /Users/mick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/mick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Which happened when `delayed_job` tried:

```
YAML.load(my_job.handler)
```

([others had the same issue before me](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/delayed_job/lfsTwEoW0o0/0Aagj3br2bYJ))

After finding the problematic `Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job` instance, a `puts my_job.handler` would show:

```
object: !ruby/ActiveRecord:MyActiveRecord
  attributes:
    id: 7648
    ... some good stuff ...
    my_field: ?   bla bla bla
    ... some other good stuff ...
method_name: :mail
args: []
```

I first thought it was an encoding issue but I realized the '?' character was a real '?' character (i.e. value 63) and not a misinterpretation of an unrecognized character.

Then I tried to create a new instance of my active record class with a `my_field` value of `?  Totot` but then the YAML looked like the following:

```
object: !ruby/ActiveRecord:MyActiveRecord
  attributes:
    id: 7648
    ... some good stuff ...
    my_field: ! '?   bla bla bla'
    ... some other good stuff ...
method_name: :mail
args: []
```

and the `YAML.load(...)` ran successfully.

So my questions are:

1. Any idea how I got a messy YAML in my database?
2. Any idea how I should sanitize my params to avoid such a problem?
3. Any idea how I can try to reproduce this in a unit test? (to be sure I'm actually fixing it with step 2)

Comment: One way is to not use DelayedJob, and if you're going to continue to use what is probably one of the worst background-job libraries, you should at least not hand it non-primitive objects for serialization.

Comment: I've been trying sidekiq on newer projets but didn't fall in love with it either.

Comment: Sidekiq, and Celluloid (the actor-pattern library that powers it) is awesome. If you have an issue with it (that isn't related to threading-ignorant libraries not working with it) I've got to wonder if the rest of your code isn't a complete nightmare. Still, there are other alternatives: Resque, Girl Friday, Bunny, Beanstalk, Qu, IronWorker…etc.

Comment: You're the rudest helpful person I met on SO. I like your style. :)

Comment: Hahaha. I'm definitely not intending to be rude, just sharing informed opinions without worrying about disagreeing. Let the best ideas win, and to hell with how anybody *feels* about them. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A detailed explanation of what @house9 is suggesting:

Do NOT do the following (even though the delayed_job's git repo suggests is as example)

```
Notifier.delay.signup(@user)

class NotifierMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def signup(user)
  end
end
```

as this will attempt to yaml encode `@user` (which can cause issues)

But rather, any time you have an object (especially an AR object) that has an id, you should pass the id when calling the delayed job and retrieve it later:

```
Notifier.delay.signup(@user.id)

class NotifierMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def signup(id)
     @user = User.find_by_id(id)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

> Any idea how I should sanitize my params to avoid such a problem?

Do not serialize your activerecord objects, instead just serialize the AR id, then do a find as the first step in the job.

Not sure why your serialized AR is corrupted, did your schema change between the time the serialization occured and before the job ran?

Comment: Thanks for your input. Unfortunately, the serialization is part of the delayed_jobs gem. I'm not doing it myself. No schema change.

Comment: @DirtyHenry Actually, you can only serialize the id, but it means using the library a little differently. [See this example in the docs](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#custom-jobs).