# new_record? is true and false at the same time, breaks delayed_job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, delayed-job

We do some third party API stuff on `ip_logs` in a delayed job, all of which is in an `after_save`:

```
class IpLog < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :process_request
  def process_request
    # stuff that doesn't need to be delayed
    self.delay.process_request_delayed(remote_ip, request_data)
  end
  def process_request_delayed(remote_ip, data)
    # third party API stuff
  end
end
```

Today I added one line of code to `process_request_delayed`, to be run after I get the results of the API call:

```
def process_request_delayed(remote_ip, data)
  # third party API stuff
  check_for_fraud_based_on_ip_results
end
```

I also added a virtual attribute to the IpLog model:

```
class IpLog < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :new_user
end
```

Then I got `Jobs cannot be created for records before they\'ve been persisted` errors from delayed_job. After many print statements, I drilled it down to this line:

```
self.delay.process_request_delayed(remote_ip, request_data)
```

It doesn't enter `process_request_delayed` at all.

I dug into delayed_job's source and found that this error happens in this context:

```
if object.respond_to?(:new_record?) && object.new_record?
  raise(ArgumentError, "Jobs cannot be created for records before they\'ve been persisted")
end
```

Since `process_request_delayed` runs in an after_save, I think the `ip_log` object *has* to not be `new_record?`. But I checked anyway, and I got this baffling screenshot:

[image]

(sorry about the blackouts; I'm not allowed to reveal business logic)

I further drilled down the offending code to this line in `UsersController`:

```
  @ip_log = IpLog.new()
  @ip_log.new_user = true // take this line out and all is well
  @ip_log.save
```

So, why do you think this is? We use Rails 3.2.17 and delayed_job_active_record (0.3.3).

Comment: if you changed your business logic, it's probably something you changed...

Comment: That does not make my question less valid. Just because I know what changed, doesn't explain why an object is and is not a new record at the same time. Nor does it help me write the logic I want without breaking the app. Your downvote is not warranted.

Comment: My advice is to never pass objects to delayed_job but rather ids of these objects. Then, inside the delayed method, pull the object back from the database. Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21751030/226255

Comment: I believe that is because you are calling the DelayedJob in `after_save` and that means the record isn't committed to db yet hence when  `delayed_job` called new_record? it return `true` and hence the error

Comment: @Viren isn't the definition of `after_save` "after committing to database"? Or am I misunderstanding `after_save`?

Comment: after_save is not like after_commit, after_commit does ensure that the data is saved to db following a commit which is not the case in after_save although you might see the id present for your record in db but truth is that record is just not saved to db yet it in underlying layer of database which generate primary key for your record (but still  hasn't been save to db yet ) hence you might find the `new_record` returning false(becuase the underlying returning you id ) in after_save but true in delayed (because the id that got in after_save has yet to committed to db ) n hence the issue

Comment: Sorry for over confusing you just read through any db process like mysql you would understand what I meant I just remember the  link  if I'll find I'll attach it

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that! Would love to see the link.

Comment: As a test you can do this on any dummy rails project  just define a after_save and put a long sleep in therr or better but a debugger and check the `self ` you would get some id for that object but since the record is still in after_save (I.e not been committed) try to access that object from some where else(like rails console) will threw n error